# problems reading links from email with php regex

Tags: php, regex, email, imap

I'm having this very weird problem, and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a script that reads an email and grabs a username and a link (or multiple links) from the email and puts it into an array. For some reason, the links keep getting chopped off because a "= " keeps getting added for some reason. When I do a string replace on the email, before i do the regex, it doesn't replace "= ". Any idea what this problem could be??

Here is the sample email:

```
 @bill
 http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/20/kickstarter-flashr-wants-to-make-the-iphones-bezel-a-massive-notification-light/?grcc=88888Z0ZwdgtZ0Z0Z0Z0Z0&grcc2=835637c33f965e6cdd34c87219233711~1342828462249~fca4fa8af1286d8a77f26033fdeed202~510f37324b14c50a5e9121f955fac3fa~1342747216490~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~7~3~
```

When I echo out the body of the message I get:

```
 --00248c6a671acfdb9c04c558d753 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable @bill http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/20/kickstarter-flashr-wants-to-make-the-iphon= es-bezel-a-massive-notification-light/?grcc=3D88888Z0ZwdgtZ0Z0Z0Z0Z0&grcc2= =3D835637c33f965e6cdd34c87219233711~1342828462249~fca4fa8af1286d8a77f26033f= deed202~510f37324b14c50a5e9121f955fac3fa~1342747216490~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~7~3~ --00248c6a671acfdb9c04c558d753 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable @bill
```

notice the "= " which breaks the link. 
My regex produces:

```
 Array ( [0] => http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/20/kickstarter-flashr-wants-to-make-the-iphon= [1] => http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/2= [2] => http://techcrunch.com/2012= )
```

When I copy and paste the string and and run it though string replace then it replaces the "= "

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Wow... That was easy... I spent hours on this problem. Argh!

Comment: If you put that as an answer I'll give you the credit for it. Thanks!

Comment: Also take a look into the PHP imap extension. It has a lot of good functions to parse emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is in an encoding called "Quoted Printable". Decode it first into normal text:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php